# prepareForSegue() Method

Tags: ios, swift

We use `prepareForSegue()` method to send data from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`.
However, this is `override` method. This means that `FirstViewController` class inherits this method from `UIViewController` class.

What is the task of this method in `UIViewController` class ?

Why don't we invoke `super.prepareForResult()` method in `override` version of it ?

Comment: [The default implementation of this method does nothing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple documentation

> The default implementation of this method does nothing.

So that means that the superclass implementation does nothing and no need to override the method like

```
super.prepareForReuse()
```

Actually it is something like template method pattern. "Don't call us we will call you". The UIViewController class calls this method when it needs and subclasses overrides it and add implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score -2):

I used to use prepareForSegue but then I realized it was too much trouble. Instead just **create your variable that you wanted to send directly above/below where you import**, like so:

```
import UIKit

var myVariable = "Hello"

class ViewController: UIViewController{...
```

Then the variable will be **accessible from any view controller** without having to use a segue.

So for example, in a button action (In same view controller let's say) I may say:

```
myVariable = "Goodbye"
```

Then I can go into my **other view controller**, and in viewDidLoad or wherever you want to access the variable, **you can edit the variable or do whatever**, example:

```
viewDidLoad{
print(myVariable)
// Goodbye
}
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. You shouldn't pass data around via global variables.

Comment: @idz except it is a solution that works. So I wouldn't call it terrible advice thank you

Comment: The main problem of this is that you show your variable to everyone. So, everyone can access it and change it. If you will set a lot of global variables, it will be terrible to debug this, because there are a lot of cases when someone could change some global variable and nobody knows it.

Comment: simply don't make it visible to the user. That easy. @iamirzhan

Comment: @AndyLebowitz if a mosquito lands on my hand I can kill it with a hammer. It will totally work, however there may be undesirable consequences, e.g. I may break my hand. So "kill mosquitos on your person with a hammer", while it works, is terrible advice. Using global variables to communicate between parts of your program similarly has lots of nasty side effects: litters global namespace, hard to debug, breaks encapsulation, creates mutable shared state, limits code reuse ... etc.

Comment: @idz i am sorry but that reference was so inaccurately cringy I kinda want to kms

Comment: @AndyLebowitz perhaps, if your avatar is accurate you'll prefer this. It is perfectly legal to underarm serve in tennis, but professionals don't. ;-)